# How to diagnose leaked http connections (org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a multithreaded java program that runs on Amazon's EC2. It queries and fetches data items from a vendor via HttpPost and HttpGet, using a org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.  Concurrently, it pushes the retrieved data items into S3 using AWS's Java SDK.

After a few days of running, I get the symptoms that normally come with http connection leaks:

```
org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute.getEntryBlocking(ConnPoolByRoute.java:417)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute$1.getPoolEntry(ConnPoolByRoute.java:300)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager$1.getConnection(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:224)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:391)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
```

Since both AWS and my requests to the data vendor use Http connections, I am not quite sure where exactly I forget to `HttpEntity.consume()`, or `S3ObjectInputStream.close()` (unless it is yet something else...).

So here is my question: are there ways to monitor `org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute` so that at least I can **detect** when I am starting to leak connections/entities not properly consumed/http streams not closed? (I have a feeling it happens only under certain conditions, e.g. when certain exceptions are being thrown, by-passing the logic in my code that consumes HttpEntities, closes streams, etc.) Any idea on how to diagnose what eventually causes all my http connections to fail with that ConnectionPoolTimeoutException would be most welcome.  I don't feel like waiting 4+ days between attempts to fix the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the `PoolingClientConnectionManager` note there are the methods `getTotalStats()` and `getStats(final HttpRoute route)` which will give you a PoolStats object with the data you're looking to monitor.

Just fetch the ConnectionManager from your httpclient:

```
PoolingClientConnectionManager poolManager = (PoolingClientConnectionManager) httpClient.getConnectionManager();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the `org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute` then set it's connTTL to a low enough value so that it's `WaitingThreadAborter` will eventually terminate a connection. It will show a nice stacktrace there. The other option is to use CGLIB or some other bytecode manipulating framework to create a proxy class wrapping `org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute`. Depending on your environment it might not be that easy to set it up, but it's a rather valuable tool to debug issues like yours. (And yes, if you happen to use spring or just plain Aspects the setup will be supereasy :) )

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the tips! BTW, I ended up finding my problem (Exceptions causing me to return early). I debugged by setting `org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager=DEBUG` and count the `Get Connection` vs `Released Connection` for each thread via a perl one-liner. I saw that there were some Released Connection that were missing here and there and searched for Exceptions before that. Now it seems pretty tight (the counts match now). Thanks to the excellent post [here](http://http://blog.nigelsim.org/2011/06/17/debugging-connection-pool-leak-in-apache-http-client/).